# How to return an object if present otherwise return optional empty

Tags: java, spring, option-type

I have an object which I am retrieving over a rest call. I need an object within that object.

`final Optional<A> aResponse = Optional.ofNullable(restTemplate.getForObject(uri, A.class));`

In class `A`, it has an object of type `B` inside it. This object could be null for whatever reason.

I am trying to query this as safely as possible so null pointer exception doesn't rise. 
I have tried doing this:

```
  final Optional<B> bType = aResponse.map(A::getB)
           .orElseGet(() -> {
        return Optional.empty();
     });
```

but it doesn't seem to work. It's giving the following message: `Required B but empty was inferred to Optional<T> no instances.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to call `orElseGet`, just:

```
final Optional<B> bType = aResponse.map(A::getB);
```

`map` already returns an `Optional` if the instance of which it is called is empty.

The Javadoc of `map`:

> **Returns:** an Optional describing the result of applying a mapping function to the value of this Optional, if a value is present,otherwise an empty Optional